# Apache directory permissions problem

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, file-permissions

I have a problem with a web application and its cache directory (I'm using symfony)

This cache directory is populated by the www-data user when visiting the application pages.  The cache can also be populated or deleted executing some commands from console.

The problem is I use this machine for development and I need to access via web, and flush caches, create new models, etc via console.

Currently I have 777 permissions to make it writable by anyone. If I browse a page (and the cache is generated) I can't, for example, create a new model because I don't have permissions to alter the files generated by www-data. I must use sudo. But then, the files have root permissions and can't be written by apache, and the page crashes...

How can I make this directory (and its dinamically-generated contents) writable by both users?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is I use this machine for development" -- yeah, that is a problem.  Stop doing that, or at least use a separate app instance ([developmestuction](http://www.google.com/search?q=developmestuction) is no fun).

To make a directory writable by both you and the webserver, you can either use extended ACLs to grant the webserver write access:

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:rwX /whatever/you/like
```

Or grant the webserver group (probably `www-data` write access to the directory:

```
chgrp www-data /whatever/you/like; chmod g+w /whatever/you/like
```

The latter choice may require root privs (if you're not a member of the `www-data` group), and the former may not work if extended ACLs aren't enabled on your server.